# Get and Set String Property returning Empty Property

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get and set a property using the following code.
But the when trying to print the property using Console,it returns an empty string.Why is the property not getting set?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        myclass x=new myclass();
        x.myproperty="test";
        Console.WriteLine(x.myproperty);
    }
     class myclass{
        string sample;
        public string myproperty
        {
            get { return sample;}
            set {sample=myproperty;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is in `set {sample=myproperty;}` You start with a null property value because you never initialized its value and more importantly because the value it has been asigned in a property in the setter method is accesed with `value` and you are trying to access it with `myproperty`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In setter you should use `value` to assign new value to underlying field
use this instead

```
public string myproperty
{
    get { return sample; }
    set { sample = value; }
}
```

or in C#7

```
public string myproperty
{
    get => sample; 
    set => sample = value; 
}
```

### Edit

As @bradbury9 mentioned, you can also use [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties), of course this is the case if you don't want any other logic in `getter` and `setter` than just getting and setting the field,   if this is the case you can use below snippet

```
 public string myproperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: You could add an alternative, those usefull auto-implemented properties.

Answer (score 1):

value keyword is important for setting the value. In Visual Studio you can use propfull + double tab to avoid such common mistakes. It will create full property through shortcuts.

Here is the solution

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        myclass x = new myclass();
        x.myproperty = "test";
        Console.WriteLine(x.myproperty);
    }
    class myclass
    {
        string sample;
        public string myproperty
        {
            get { return sample; }
            set { sample = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return null instead of empty string. This works even when you deserialize your Json:

```
class myclass
{
    string sample;
    [JsonProperty("my_property")]
    public string My_property
    {
        get { return sample; }
        set { sample = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : value; }
    }
}
```